# add mysql database table names to php array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I need to write some code that cycles through the entire list of tables I have in my database, so first I need to get the list of all tables and add them to an array.

I'm trying to do this using this code:

```
include('./db.php');

$dataList = array();
$showTable = "SHOW TABLES from databaseA";
$getData = mysqli_query($con, $showTable);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($getData)) {
    $dataList[] = $row;
    print_r($row); 
    }
```

My results are showing as:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Dave
        )
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Bob
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Chris
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => Matt
    )
}
```

but if I use `echo $dataList[0];` or `echo $dataList[1];` I just get the word `array` by itself.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here...

I then need to build a php for loop utilizing this, and my initial thought was to do something like this:

```
for ($i=0; $i <= count($dataList); $i++) {}
```

but that's not working since I'm defining the array incorrectly....

Comment: You are building array of arrays as @Marc says. For this to work, you would have work on the inner array when getting values. Check out [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're building an array-of-arrays:

```
$data[] = $row;
           ^---array
     ^---push onto another array
```

You need

```
$data[0][0] -> Dave
$data[1][0] -> Chris
etc...
```

a `var_dump($data)` would've shown you this. Echoing out an array in a string context will give you the word `Array` - PHP won't stringify the array for you.

Comment: This is great!  Thank you for explaining the double array.  How do I build a for statement with this double array?  I've tried `for ($i=0;$i=count($dataList);$i++) {} ` but it just hangs...

Comment: `foreach ($data as $subarray) { echo $subarray[0] }`

Answer (score 1):

Move the `print_r` outside the the `While` statement and print the `$datalist` instead of $row

```
include('./db.php');

$dataList = array();
$showTable = "SHOW TABLES from databaseA";
$getData = mysqli_query($con, $showTable);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($getData)) {
   $dataList[] = $row;
}

print_r($dataList);
```

Answer (score 1):

@Marc B are right. But I want show some other way (may be, trick):

```
 $dataList = array_reduce($dataList, 'array_merge', array());
 foreach($dataList as $name){
      echo $name;
 }
 // Dave
 // Bob
 // Below
```

In code above - "unwrapping first-level array" in 2D-array.

Comment: This is wonderful!  I can't upvote you yet, but I really appreciate this response.  Breaking it down into a single array is really helpful for me.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

If it echos the word `array` then that means it is an array.

Try

```
print_r($dataList);
```

This will probably be an array of arrays.